# Ошибочная причина невозможности закрытия вопроса, если тот уже был закрыт, во время просмотра страницы пользователем

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, закрытие-вопросов

Последовательность событий:

- Зашел на страницу с **открытым** вопросом: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/533674/Задача-про-волшебный-рубль](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/533674/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8C).
- *После загрузки у меня вкладки с вопросом, кто-то закрывает вопрос. Я этого не знаю.*
- Посчитал нужным закрыть вопрос, как не относящийся к тематике сайта.
- Нажал на ссылку закрыть вопрос.
- Получил сообщение об ошибке, несоответствующее ситуации:
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- Подождал несколько секунд (больше трех) и снова попытался закрыть вопрос.
- Снова получил это сообщение об ошибке.
- Обновил страницу и увидел, что вопрос уже закрыт.

Я считаю, что выдаваемое системой сообщение об ошибке не соответствует причине ее возникновения и только сбивает с толку пользователя. Следует заменить его на более подходящее для такой ситуации.

Comment: Любопытно. Надо как-нибудь повоспроизводить на тестовом вопросе.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, за последние дни уже четыре раза сталкивался с этим глюком, но забывал заскриншотить страницу до того, как обновлял ее.

Comment: Баг подтверждаю. Я такое часто вижу, когда перехожу по ссылкам из чата :)

Comment: Аналогично. Встретил этот баг в очереди на закрытие. Открыл очередь, попроверял чего-то, пошёл налить чаю, мне позвонили... ~/ опущены подробности захватывающих приключений /~ ...и когда я вернулся и попытался закрыть вопрос, мне выдало это.